# Problemas al obtener elementos HTML desde Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, css, android-studio, firebase

Tengo una base de datos en Firebase que recibe datos desde una aplicación Android, la aplicación manda los datos ya encerrados en etiquetas HTML, con clases y Id's. Yo obtengo los datos de Firebase con Javascript y los imprimo en pantalla. los datos se muestran correctamente. Pero al parecer sobrescribe todo sobre el archivo HTML ya que al archivo le agrego un elemento h1 para darle un titulo y al cargar al proyecto me muestra el elemento h1 pero enseguida desaparece y se muestran los datos obtenidos desde Firebase. Tampoco me deja darle estilos, los selecciono con las clases con las que ya vienen los elementos pero al parecer no los lee.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js">
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="referenceFirebase.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosPedido.css">
<title>Prueba</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1> Pedidos</h1>

 <script src="pruebaPedido.js"></script>

</body>

</html>


 ---------------------- CSS ------------------------

 * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}



.divPedidos {
background: #FF8A33;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
}

p {
background: #FF8A33;
font-size: 50px;
}



--------------------- archivo JS --------------------


  var referenceMesa = databaseRefence.child('Mesa3');
  var referencePedidos = referenceMesa.child('Pedidos');
  var referenceUsuario = referencePedidos.child('Usuario1');
  var referencePedido = referenceUsuario.child('Pedido1');

var pedido1;


referencePedido.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {

 pedido1 = snapshot.val();

console.log(pedido1);
setTimeout(prueba, 1000);
});

function prueba() {

document.write(pedido1);
 }
```

[image: Estos son los elemento que se muestran y la consola donde aparecen los div, clases y id]

Comment: Es que estás usando `document.write`. [La doc dice esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write):  ***Nota: dado que document.write escribe directo al hilo (stream) de un documento, la llamada a document.write en un documento ya cargado automáticamente ejecuta document.open, lo cual [limpiará todo el contenido del documento en cuestión](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open#Notes).** Debes adjuntar el contenido obtenido de F. Base a algún elemento del DOM.

Comment: Prueba a poner esto en el DOM: `<div id="firebase"></div>` y en Javascript en vez de `document.write`, pones algo así:  `var divFireBase= document.getElementById('firebase'); divFireBase.innerHTML = pedido1;` O bien lo pones en el `divPedidos` si es ahí donde los quieres mostrar: **`divPedidos.innerHTML = pedido1;`**

Comment: Hola buenas tardes. Gracias por responder. Te refieres a crear un div u algún otro elemento desde mi Js e insertarlo ahi?

Comment: Perfecto, probare, muchas gracias.

Comment: No tienes que crearlo necesariamente desde JS, lo puedes tener en el DOM o, según se muestra en la imagen, poner el contenido de la variable `pedido1` en el div con id `divPedidos`, si quieres mostrar el contenido en ese div. O sea, sería hacer esto: **`divPedidos.innerHTML = pedido1;`** sin olvidar de **quitar la línea de `document.write`**

Comment: Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible lee: ๏̯͡๏ **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## El problema

El problema es que estás usando `document.write` para mostrar los datos obtenidos de Firebase.

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> `document.write` escribe directo al hilo (stream) de un documento, la
>   llamada a `document.write` en un documento ya cargado automáticamente
>   ejecuta `document.open`, lo cual [**limpiará todo el contenido del
>   documento en cuestión**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open#Notes).

---

## Solución

Debes borrar esta línea en la función `prueba()`:

<s>`document.write(pedido1);`</s>

Y agregar el contenido obtenido de Firebase a algún elemento existente en el DOM.

Por la imagen se puede deducir que debes tener un div con el id `divPedidos`.

Algo así en el HTML:

```
<div id="divPedidos"></div>
```

Entonces, la función quedaría así:

```
function prueba() {
    /*Creas una referencia al elemento por su id*/
    divPedidos= document.getElementById('divPedidos');

    /*Le pones el contenido de la variable pedido1*/
    divPedidos.innerHTML = pedido1;
}
```

**NOTA:** Si te interesa mostrarlo en otro contenedor, puedes tenerlo creado en el DOM y cargas los datos como explicado antes, cambiando solamente la referencia al elemento que obtienes con `document.getElementById`.